# Data is not bound to templates in angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the results on search,I think the code is correct but the data is not bound. Yet I can see the results in the console.Can someone please help me?

My Template:

```
        <div id="header-wrap">

            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="divcenter" style="max-width:990px;">
                    <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>

                    <!-- Logo
                ============================================= -->
                    <div id="logo" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                        <a href="#" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark.png"><img src="assets/images/SW-Logo-Final.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>


                    </div>
                    <span class="inputgroupcss col-sm-5" style="padding-top:12px;">


                                    <input type="email"  (keyup)=0 (keyup)='submit(button.value)' #button  class="form-control required email" placeholder="Search by Name or Email"
                                        style="height:38px;">

                                <div  class="col-sm-12 nopadding ">

                                <ul class="searchlist">
                                    <li *ngFor="let detail of details">
                                        <img [src]='detail.image' alt="profile_image" style="width: 35px;
                            height: 35px;">
                                        <a [routerLink]="['/demo/user',detail.profilename]">{{detail.profilename}}</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>    
                            </div>


                        </span>


                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </header>
```

My Component,

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,provideRouter} from '@angular/router';
    import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { GetAllList } from './components/society/service';
    import { ISearch } from './components/search/details';
    import { IDetails } from './components/society/pro';
    import {Location} from '@angular/common';

    declare var System: any,jQuery:any;
 @Component({
    selector: 'demo-page',
      templateUrl: './demo-page.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
      providers: [GetAllList],
   })

  export class DemoPage {
     location:Location;
     details: ISearch[];
      list:IDetails[];
       constructor(location:Location,public http: Http,private _service:GetAllList) {
         this.location = location;
      //   console.log(this.location.path());
                this._service.getList()
            .subscribe(list => this.list = list);
          console.log(this.list);
     }

      submit(id): any {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    this.http.get('http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/search/' + id, { headers: headers })
           .subscribe(response => {
            if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
                   this.details = <ISearch[]>response.json().data;
                   // console.log(this.details);
            } else {
                this.details = [];
            }
            if (id == '') {
                this.details = [];
            }

        }

             )}


      }
```

my console,

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Objectactive: "1"connection_status: nullcountry: "Greenland"email: "s@gmail.com"firstname: "Sachin"friends_count: "5"image: ""lastname: "Tendulkar"password: "1"phone: "2"profile_id: "1"profilename: "sachin tendulkar"relation_id: nullrepeatpassword: nullstatus: "1"street: "Perry Cross Road,Mumbai"type: nullzip: ""__proto__: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Objectlength: 9__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: please show the printed output on console. is it really an array? OR maybe id is every time EMPTY and the list is cleared immediately ?! code looks ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (id == '') {
    this.details = [];
}
```

maybe this is executed?!

Code seems fine.

Comment: Yes @mxii,u r absolutely correct but can you tell me how to get the solution ....i am not able to send the value that i searched to my ts.....

Comment: i am not able to see the value in console

Comment: i dont know, your way of doint it is correct. look at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8CaPrjxb7g6KC9tKDkck?p=preview

Comment: i had done the same think like u but y its not working for me

Comment: yw! what/where was the fault? :)

Answer (score 1):

why do you have twice the keyup event binding in your html? (keyup)=0 (keyup)='submit(button.value)', remove the first one

Comment: stil no use...........the problem is i am not getting the seached keyword to my ts

Answer (score 0):

The class field is named "details" but in your template you've written "detail". Shouldn't it be:

```
{{details.profilename}}
```

Comment: I am looping in details as detail